# Adding condition to mysql query and fetch again

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 3 queries which I run which are nearly identical, the latter two have an `AND` condition.

Main query:

```
$mess = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * from ( SELECT cm.id ,cm.userid,cm.message,cm.voteup,cm.votedown,cm.date
                        FROM chat_messages cm 
                        INNER JOIN members m  ON m.id =cm.userid
                        INNER JOIN chat_settings cs ON cs.id = cm.room_id 
                        WHERE cm.setting_id = ?          
                        ORDER BY cm.date DESC LIMIT 30 ) ddd
                        ORDER BY date ASC ");
$mess->bind_param("i", $room);                              
$mess->execute();
$mess->store_result();

$mess->bind_result($chatid,$chat_userid,$message,$voteup,$votedown,$date);
while($row = $mess->fetch()){
    //im fetching here in my <div class='div1' >
}
```

Then, in the second `div` I have to add an `AND` condition:

```
$mess2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * from ( SELECT cm.id ,cm.userid,cm.message,cm.voteup,cm.votedown,cm.date
                        FROM chat_messages cm 
                        INNER JOIN members m  ON m.id =cm.userid
                        INNER JOIN chat_settings cs ON cs.id = cm.room_id
                        WHERE cm.setting_id = ?    AND voteup - votedown >= 5      
                        ORDER BY cm.date DESC LIMIT 30 ) ddd
                            ORDER BY date ASC ");
$mess2->bind_param("i", $room);                              
$mess2->execute();
$mess2->store_result();

$mess2->bind_result($chatid,$chat_userid,$message,$voteup,$votedown,$date);
while($row2 = $mess2->fetch()){
    //im fetching here in my <div class='div2' >
}
```

Lastly, in the third `div` I have a slightly different `AND` condition:

```
$mess3 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * from ( SELECT cm.id ,cm.userid,cm.message,cm.voteup,cm.votedown,cm.date
                        FROM chat_messages cm 
                        INNER JOIN members m  ON m.id =cm.userid
                        INNER JOIN chat_settings cs ON cs.id = cm.room_id 
                        WHERE cm.setting_id = ?    AND votedown - voteup >= 5      
                        ORDER BY cm.date DESC LIMIT 30 ) ddd
                            ORDER BY date ASC ");
$mess3->bind_param("i", $room);                              
$mess3->execute();
$mess3->store_result();

$mess3->bind_result($chatid,$chat_userid,$message,$voteup,$votedown,$date);
while($row3 = $mess3->fetch()){
    //im fetching here in my <div class='div3' >
}
```

Everything works *BUT* doing this near-same query seems clumsy. Is it possible to construct the same thing with only one query? I have used `$mess->data_seek(0);` but its not helping because I didn't add my condition to the query.

Comment: What about you gather the larger set, and then reduce it using PHP and the columns you have?

Comment: You could filter to know which line insert in the appropriate div using PhP, with your single query (the third).

Comment: @JulienLachal this can happen if i fetch in one div , but they are 3 different divs . AND also other problem , in first query i have limit 30. so if i run the first many data which supposed to come in second div dont come . only if i put this AND condition which will bring just those and limit to 30 .

Comment: I am an sql guru so I can not help from that sense because there may be a way to create an sql statement that would do this in one shot, but if this had to remain 3 calls, to clean it up I would wrap the first instance in a function that I could feed some values into whereby the sql statement was the general statement and depending on the parameters, would add in the `and` clauses into the string to modify the original. That way you just have one function that you use 3 times with parameters in the 2nd and 3rd instance.

Comment: I should modify my previous comment, I meant to write "I am NOT an sql..." That will come across as confusing... :)

Answer (score 1):

Just go for PhP to filter your data instead of triple query your database. In this case you can figure out to go for this solution because you call 3 times your query with the same parameter :

```
    $mess3  =   $mysqli->prepare("  SELECT    * 
                                    FROM      ( SELECT  cm.id ,
                                                        cm.userid,
                                                        cm.message,
                                                        cm.voteup,
                                                        cm.votedown,
                                                        cm.date
                                                FROM        chat_messages cm 
                                                INNER JOIN  members m  ON m.id =cm.userid
                                                INNER JOIN  chat_settings cs ON cs.id = cm.room_id 
                                                WHERE       cm.setting_id = ?    
                                                AND         votedown - voteup >= 5      
                                                ORDER BY    cm.date DESC LIMIT 30 ) ddd
                                    ORDER BY   date ASC ");
$mess3->bind_param("i", $room);                              
$mess3->execute();
$mess3->store_result();
$mess3->bind_result($chatid,$chat_userid ,$message,$voteup,$votedown ,$date);

while($row = $mess3->fetch()){
  $voteup     =   $row['voteup'];
  $votedown   =   $row['votedown'];

  addToDiv1($row);

  if( $voteup - $votedown >= 5 ) {
    addToDiv2($row);
  }

  if( $votedown - $voteup >= 5 ) {
    addToDiv3($row);
  } 
}
```

Comment: No sir , totally wrong . i cant fetch normal data in div1 without condition , i cant get data to div 2 because is totally the opposit `voteup-votedown >=5` it will never come in the third query .

Comment: In fact, if you try to compare your 3 bloc of code, you will detect which is redundant and which is not, that is why the code above is simplified. I do not see the change between `$mess2` query and `$mess3`. Is that ok you call twice the same query or am I wrong ?

Comment: I thought the same but then noticed it's changing on the voteup and votedown equations

Comment: they are not same 2 and 3rd look in `AND` condition . the second have `AND voteup - votedown >= 5`  and the 3rd have `AND votedown - voteup >= 5` they cant be same results

Comment: @Rasclatt Noticed now ! @Scooter Daraf so you will have a second `if` statement for the third condition so. Did you tryied it ?

Comment: If you look in the first statement though, there is just a general select statement, no equation. The the latter two use different equations on the votes. You are using the votedown version, so that wouldn't cover the other two. Do you mean to remove that `and` portion?

Comment: Then let's say you did remove that, there is a limit, which suggests there are more than 30 so possibly the OP wants the first 30 of the total but out of the total then wants to narrow it down by equation, so that could not be from the same group of 30 from the general call, that would have to be from the total.

Comment: @Rasclatt you are good observer , he uses the 3rd query which is filtered from the 1st query

Comment: @Rasclatt exactly what you said in your last comment. with my second query for example i will fetch 30 other results which may not been in first when the first fetched 30 . you understood me good .

Answer (score 1):

I will just give an answer based specifically on cleaning up your code. Technically you will still make the 3 calls in this scenario, but it will be cleaner because you include one function only, you don't see the script behind it.

As I mentioned, I am not an SQL aficionado so I can not give a good solution there (maybe you can use `GROUP BY` and perhaps an `OR` clause...I don't really know...). If I were to do this, I would do a function that can return all the options:

**/core/functions/getChatMessages.php**

```
function getChatMessages($settings,$mysqli)
    {
        $id   = (!empty($settings['id']))? $settings['id'] : false;
        $type = (!empty($settings['type']))? $settings['type'] : false;
        $max  = (!empty($settings['max']))? $settings['max'] : 30;
        $mod  = '';
        // No id, just stop
        if(!is_numeric($id))
            return false;
        // equation one
        if($type == 'up')
            $mod = ' AND voteup - votedown >= 5';
        // equation two
        elseif($type == 'down')
            $mod = ' AND votedown - voteup >= 5';

        $mess = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * from ( SELECT cm.id ,cm.userid,cm.message,cm.voteup,cm.votedown,cm.date
                            FROM chat_messages cm 
                            INNER JOIN members m  ON m.id =cm.userid
                            INNER JOIN chat_settings cs ON cs.id = cm.room_id 
                            WHERE cm.setting_id = ? {$mod}     
                            ORDER BY cm.date DESC LIMIT {$max} ) ddd
                            ORDER BY date ASC");
        $mess->bind_param("i", $id);
        $mess->execute();
        $mess->store_result();
        $mess->bind_result($chatid, $chat_userid, $message, $voteup, $votedown, $date);
        while($mess->fetch()){
            $result[] = array(
                            'chatid'=>$chatid,
                            'chat_userid'=>$chat_userid,
                            'message'=>$message,
                            'voteup'=>$voteup,
                            'votedown'=>$votedown
                        );
        }
        // Send back the data
        return (!empty($result))? $result : array();
    }
```

**To use:**

```
// Include our handy function
require_once('/core/functions/getChatMessages.php');
// Store our id for use
$settings['id'] = 100;
// Should get 30 from first select
$voteGen = getChatMessages($settings,$mysqli);
// Should get 30 from second select
$settings['type'] = 'up';
$voteUp = getChatMessages($settings,$mysqli);
// Should get 15 from third select
// Just for the heck of it, I added in a limit settings
$settings['max'] = 15;
$settings['type'] = 'down';
$voteDown = getChatMessages($settings,$mysqli);
```

Now that you have these stored, just use a `foreach` loop to place them into your view. The good side of this is that you can call this where ever and when ever since the function only returns data. It allows you to work with the data in a view or non-view situation. *Side note, I use PDO, so if there is something ineffective with the way the `mysqli` is fetching, that will be why. It's probably just best to fetch an assoc array to return...*